# Removing rows when flipped in two columns

Tags: r

Considering the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = c(5,6,7,8,1))

> df
  var1 var2
1    1    5
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
5    5    1
```

I'd like to remove all rows whose values are flipped across the two columns. In this case, it would be *row 1* and *row 5* as the values 1 and 5 in row 1 are flipped to 5 and 1 in row 5. These two rows should be removed.

I hope it came clear what I am asking for :-)

Kind regards!

Comment: Are you looking for the values that match?

Comment: Yep! That match and are flipped at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could work too:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = c(5,6,7,8,1))
df[!do.call(paste, df) %in% do.call(paste, rev(df)), ]
  var1 var2
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
```

I'd have to test it on a few more test cases though, but the general idea is to use `rev` to reverse the order of the columns in "df" and `paste` them together and compare that with the pasted columns from "df".

Comment: +1 If I were maintaining somebody else's code, this is the one I'd want to see. Elegant and easy to understand.

Comment: Works well! How do I deal with it when having factors?

Comment: @ahs85, can you explain further what you mean? The same approach should work as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple but not especially elegant way: make a reversed data frame with a flag, and then merge it on to `df`:

```
# Make a reversed dataset
fd <- data.frame(var1 = df$var2, var2 = df$var1, flag = TRUE)

# Merge it onto your original df, then drop the matched rows and the flag var
df.sub <- subset(merge(x = df, y = fd, by = c("var1", "var2"), all.x = TRUE),
                subset = is.na(flag),
                select = c("var1", "var2"))
```

Comment: or just `fd <- df[,ncol(df):1] `

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit of maths - the two rows are the same up to a permutation if the sum and absolute value of difference are the same:

```
df[with(df, !duplicated(data.frame(var1 + var2, abs(var1 - var2)), fromLast = TRUE)),]
#  var1 var2
#1    1    5
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4    4    8
```

**edit:** should've read the question more carefully, to remove both duplicates, follow Ananda's suggestion:

```
df.ind = with(df, data.frame(var1 + var2, abs(var1 - var2)))
df[!duplicated(df.ind) & !duplicated(df.ind, fromLast = TRUE),]
#  var1 var2
#2    2    6
#3    3    7
#4    4    8
```

Comment: You'll need to do this both ways (in other words, `duplicated` with "from last") to drop both "duplicated" rows.

Answer (score 0):

If creating a copy doesn't cause memory issues then this works as well -

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = c(5,6,7,8,1))
df2 <- data.frame(var12 = 1:5, var22 = c(5,6,7,8,1))
df3 <- merge(df,df2, by.x = 'var2', by.y = 'var12', all.x = TRUE)
df3 <- subset(
   df3, 
   is.na(var22),
   select = c('var1','var2')
)
```

Output:

```
> df3
  var1 var2
3    2    6
4    3    7
5    4    8
```

I tried merging df with df but that gives a warning about the column var2 being duplicated. Anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume there are no duplicates in the data frame.  Here's a one line answer, but still not too concise:

```
df[!duplicated(rbindlist(list(df,df[,2:1])))[nrow(df) + 1:nrow(df)],]
##   var1 var2
## 2    2    6
## 3    3    7
## 4    4    8
```

`rbindlist` is necessary here because `rbind(df,df[,2:1])` will match by column name rather than index, so the other option is something like `rbind(df,setnames(df[,2:1],names(df)))`. If you want to keep duplicates from the original, this gets even more unpleasant:

```
> df <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5, var2 = c(5,6,7,8,1))
> df<-rbind(df,c(2,6))
> df[!duplicated(rbindlist(list(df,df[,2:1])))[nrow(df)+1:nrow(df)],]
  var1 var2
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
> df[!duplicated(rbindlist(list(df,df[,2:1])))[nrow(df)+1:nrow(df)] | duplicated(df),]
  var1 var2
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
6    2    6
```